# model can predict new image

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)  in () ----> 1 prediction = model.predict(image_resized.reshape(1,50,50,3))       2 print('Prediction Score:\n',prediction[0])  ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2352 into shape (1,50,50,3)

Comment: Do you want something? Give more information, be specific, check this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

By just looking at what you have posted you should replace `image_resized.reshape(1,50,50,3)` with `image_resized.reshape(1,28,28,3)`